# Positioning Graphic within Tikzpicture

Tags: beamer, tikz-node

I'm making a LaTeX presentation for the first time, and I'm trying to make a flowchart including a graphic, but for some reason the positioning of the graphic is above and to the right of where it should be. The Gaussian distribution should show up where the arrow is pointing below it.

[image: Slide]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

%% Defining tikz drawing primitives
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{whiteblock} = [rectangle, draw, 
    text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Create thresholds in standard normal based on frequencies of categorical
\item Sample a few (5) points for each categorical value in the threshold
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5cm, auto]
\node [whiteblock] (cat) {Categorical};
\node [whiteblock, right of=cat] (freq) {Frequencies};
\node [whiteblock, right of=freq] (thresh) {Thresholds};
\node [whiteblock, right of=thresh] (samp) {Sample Continuous};

\node [block, below of=cat] (catr) {A;A;B;C};
\node [block, right of=catr] (freqr) {A: 0.5, B: 0.25, C: 0.25};
\node[inner sep=1pt, right of=freqr](threshr)
    {
\begin{axis}[no markers, domain=-2:2, samples=100, xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
axis lines*=left,
height=3cm, width=4cm,
xticklabels={A,B,C}, 
ytick=\empty,
enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
grid = major]
\addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-2:0] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=orange!20, draw=none, domain=0:1] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=red!20, draw=none, domain=1:2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
    };
\node [block, right of=threshr] (sampr) {Sample Continuous};

\path [line] (cat) -- (freq);
\path [line] (freq) -- (thresh);
\path [line] (thresh) -- (samp);

\path [line] (freqr) -- (threshr);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{second}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I've also noticed that the way it currently is offsets the slides below it strangely.

[image: Offset]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: please extend your code snippets to complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{beamer}` followed by preamble and `\begin{document}`, than your code snippet ending with `\end{document}`. important are your node styles definitions too.

Comment: @Zarko Ok, added. It looks a little different as a MWE but still is offsetted incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only one question please :-)

as starting point for your image (i still need to work on your `pgfplots` image :-( )

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Categorical to Normal}
\begin{itemize}
\item Create thresholds in standard normal based on frequencies of categorical
\item Sample a few (5) points for each categorical value in the threshold
\end{itemize}

\newcommand\GAUSS{\tikz{
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
axis lines*=left,
height=3cm, width=4cm,
xticklabels={A,B,C},
ytick=\empty,
enlargelimits=false,
grid = major,
no markers,
domain=-2:2, samples=100,
]
\addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-2:0] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=orange!20, draw=none, domain=0:1] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=red!20, draw=none, domain=1:2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
            };}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 6mm and 4mm,
          start chain = A going right,
          start chain = B going right,
        wblock/.style = {draw, minimum size =24mm, align=center, on chain=A, join=by -Stealth},
         block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!30,
                         minimum size =24mm, align=center,
                         on chain=B, join=by -Stealth},
                          ]
\node [wblock] (cat)    {Categorical};
\node [wblock] (freq)   {Frequencies};
\node [wblock] (thresh) {Thresholds};
\node [wblock] (samp)   {Sample\\ Continuous};

\node [block,below=of cat] (catr)   {A;A;B;C};
\node [block] (freqr)               {A: 0.5,\\ B: 0.25,\\ C: 0.25};
\node [block, fill=white, inner sep=0pt,scale=0.4] (threshr)
                                    {\GAUSS};
\node [block] (sampr)               {Sample\\ Continuous};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

**edit:** with including `pgfplots` image in node i have hard problems. here is solution which has `pgfplot` images defined as special nodes to which style definition is included `pgfplots` code via `append after command={\pgfextra{ ...}}` mechanism.

[image]

the code for the new solution is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}%[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Categorical to Normal}

 \begin{itemize}
\item Create thresholds in standard normal based on frequencies of categorical
\item Sample a few (5) points for each categorical value in the threshold
\end{itemize}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 6mm and 4mm,
          start chain = A going right,
          start chain = B going right,
        wblock/.style = {draw, minimum size =24mm, align=center, on chain=A, join=by -Stealth},
         block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!30,
                         minimum size =24mm, align=center,
                         on chain=B, join=by -Stealth},
      pgfblock/.style = {block, fill=none,
                         append after command={\pgfextra{
\begin{axis}[at={(\tikzlastnode.south west)}, shift={(3mm,4mm)},
    width=18mm,
    scale only axis,
    axis lines=left,
    xticklabels={,,A,B,C},
    x tick label style={inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny},
    ytick=\empty,
    axis on top,
    grid,
    no markers,
]
\addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-2:0]     {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=orange!20, draw=none, domain=0:1]    {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=red!20, draw=none, domain=1:2]   {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
                    }}}
                          ]
\node [wblock] (cat)    {Categorical};
\node [wblock] (freq)   {Frequencies};
\node [wblock] (thresh) {Thresholds};
\node [wblock] (samp)   {Sample\\ Continuous};

\node [block,below=of cat] (catr)   {A;A;B;C};
\node [block] (freqr)               {A: 0.25,\\ B: 0.5,\\ C: 0.25};
\node [pgfblock] (threshr)          {};
\node [block] (sampr)               {Sample\\ Continuous};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

i'm convinced that simpler way is to draw Gauss diagram separately (using `standalone`) and include it as `pdf` images:

```
\node [block,below=of cat] (catr)   {A;A;B;C};
\node [block] (freqr)               {A: 0.5,\\ B: 0.25,\\ C: 0.25};
\node [block,fill=none] (threshr)   {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{GAUSS}}; 
\node [block] (sampr)               {Sample\\ Continuous};
```

where GAUSS is image `pdf` file produced for example by:

```
%%%% GAUSS
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=22mm,height=22mm}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis lines=left,
    xticklabels={,,A,B,C},
    x tick label style={inner sep=1pt},
    ytick=\empty,
    axis on top,
    grid,
    no markers,
            ]
\addplot [fill=cyan!20,     draw=none, domain=-2:0] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=orange!20,   draw=none, domain= 0:1] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=red!20,      draw=none, domain= 1:2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```